# Installing multiple programs c++ taking user input through array or another way

Tags: c++, arrays, input, vector

I'm writing a c++ program to install certain programs that I put on several computers.  I am putting a section in the code that will allow users to select which installs they want.  I'm very rusty on c++ so I'm having trouble with taking in the user input.  I'm open to suggestions of better ways to do this, I'm sure there are several.

```
    int allOrSelect;

std::cout << "Press 1 if you want all software, press 2 if you want to select";
std::cin >> allOrSelect;

if(allOrSelect == 1)
{
    std::cout<< "all software installing ..." <<std::endl;
}

if(allOrSelect == 2)
{
    std::cout << "Please select from the following list";
    std::cout << "software 1";
    std::cout << "software 2";
    std::cout << "software 3";
    std::cout << "software 4";
    std::cout << "Type the appropriate numbers separated by space or comma";
//this is where trouble starts
//I've tried a few different ways to take the user input
//i tried using vector array, but never got it working, but i figured there had to 
//be a simpler way.  also tried variations of cin.whatever
}
```

If you need any more information please let me know, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at `std::cin` for input and `std::endl` to output a newline at the end of each text string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user input would be comma-separated values (for example, "1, 2, 3") the input should be tokenized using the `std::istringstream` class. `std::set` is used to prevent duplicate values.

Please note that the code practically does not implement the input validation.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

// Read the string representation:
// "1, 2, 3"
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);

// Convert to set of integers.
std::set<int> selection;
std::istringstream ss(input);
std::string softItem;

while (std::getline(ss, softItem, ','))
{
    std::stringstream stm;
    stm.str(softItem);

    int i;
    if (!(stm >> i))
    {
        // TODO: handle input error!
        std::cout << "Input error!" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    selection.insert(i);
}

// Logic:
// The selection set contains the user selection.
```